# Large integers in javascript (more the 2^53-1)

Tags: javascript, biginteger, bignum

What is general principals to operate with large integers in javascript? Like in libraries for bigint? How i do it by myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript BigDecimal library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/javascript-bigdecimal-library)

Comment: In fact i don't search the library, but i want know the general principals for work like in this libraries. For example: "if you wanna work with bignum, in general, you can use the string array with number in power ^2" Thank you.

Comment: JS comes with [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) as part of the language itself, it's not a "library", it's a basic language feature that has an equivalent "primitive notation" that uses the `n` suffix for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [this implementation](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html). You may also find [other implementations](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=javascript+big+integer&aq=f&aqi=g-s1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=7db4f7af4a13aa89) useful.

Answer (score 1):

You just use the JS-native [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) (accepted into JS [in 2019](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) and released as part of ES2020), which is a number primitive for working with integers that don't fit in the original `Number` type. In primitive form it uses the `n` suffix and works with all operators that regular numbers support, but with explicit integer logic. E.g. `1n/3n` is `0n`.

Also note that this is a *different* primitive from `Number`, so even for "safe" numbers the `n` version will not strictly equal the "plain" number:

```js
const a = 1n;
const b = 1;
console.log(a === b); // false
try {
  console.log(a + b); // TypeError, you can't add a Number to a BigInt
} catch (e) {}
console.log(a + BigInt(b)); // 2n
```

Comment: Did you really answer a 13 years old question?

Comment: You bet! Times change and JS changes even faster, so old questions keep qualifying for new answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I've used in the past, is to hand off those operations to a calculation server via jsonp.  If you're working with such large numbers, you likely want the improved performance and precision this can give you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has `BigInt` now.

References:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt